# Signalling formats in WireWorld?

Tags: binary, format, signals, cellular-automata, esoteric-languages

What formats are used in the WireWorld cellular automata rule (language) for signalling between parts of a pattern (program)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A single signal that is sent like a pulse, whenever required, traveling through a line of wire cells, containing a signal head followed by a signal tail.
2. Or a series of signals of a given period (spacing). Commonly, and must be at least, 3. This appears as `WTHWTHW` etc... The inclusion or lack of each signal in the series represents `True` or `False` at each generation or moment in time. Therefore the number of generations that `True` or `False` is represented for in this format must be an integer multiple of the period of the series.
3. A third format uses the number of wire cells between adjacent signals to communicate numbers, this doesn't need a period, as format 2 requires.
4. Signalling a number can also be achieved through a series of parallel wires, the number is encoded in binary such that each wire represents a part of the number that is twice the value of the previous, see multiplexers and decoders.
5. Alternatively a large number can be practically represented in a single wire where each signal in a series of signals sequentially represents binary bits through time in the same way. While slower, finite sized circuitry can process calculations such as addition on numbers of an unlimited size.
6. Less common is a format of my own design for signalling, where `True` and `False` may be sent and `no signal` can be represented by simply not sending any signals, there is also no need for a period. This uses two close adjacent signals for `True` and a single signal for `False`. A consequence of this format includes gates that can receive there inputs at any time, creating an output and reseting as soon as both are defined, however circuitry to manage this can be large.